# Webpack ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've upgraded Webpack to the 5th version and have the following error occured:
**ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf. Original source src/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf**

**Here is webpack.config:**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

const path = require("path");

// const os = require("os");
// const ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
// let values = Object.keys(ifaces).map(function (name) {
//     return ifaces[name];
// });
// values = [].concat.apply([], values).filter(function (val) {
//     return val.family == "IPv4" && val.internal == false;
// });
// const external_ip = values[0].address || "0.0.0.0";

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  const isDev = options.mode === "development";
  const localIdentName = isDev
    ? "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
    : "[hash:base64:5]";

  const copyPlaginPattern = [
    { from: "public/icons", to: "icons" },
    { from: "public/docs", to: "docs" },
    { from: "public/attestata.webmanifest", to: "attestata.webmanifest" },
  ];

  let htmlTemplate = "./src/index.html";

  if (env === "prod") {
    copyPlaginPattern.push(
      { from: "public/robots.txt", to: "robots.txt" },
      { from: "public/sitemap.xml", to: "sitemap.xml" },
      { from: "public/sitemaphttp.xml", to: "sitemaphttp.xml" }
    );

    htmlTemplate = "./src/index.prod.html";
  }

  return {
    output: {
      filename: "[name].bundle.js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "ts-loader",
              options: {
                transpileOnly: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "html-loader",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.styl$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              // options: { publicPath: "/dist" },
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: {
                  mode: "local",
                  exportGlobals: true,
                  localIdentName: localIdentName,
                  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                  hashPrefix: "hash",
                },
              },
            },
            { loader: "stylus-loader" },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["style-loader", MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            "style-loader",
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            "css-loader",
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            "sass-loader",
          ],
        },

        {
          test: /(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "fonts/",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|pdf)$/i,
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "images",
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "video",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      alias: {
        assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/"),
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
        template: htmlTemplate,
        filename: "./index.html",
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      }),
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: copyPlaginPattern,
      }),
    ],

    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: {
        disableDotRule: true,
      },
      // host: 'attestata.loc',
      // host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: 3000,
      https: true,
      proxy: {
        "/api": "http://signatura.axamit.com:8080",
      },
    },
  };
};
```

The tree is:

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Maybe something is being cached across your builds, but I do notice that your regex for font files includes versioning. Have you tried adding `[query]` to the filename generated by `file-loader`? Something like `"[name].[query].[ext]"`.

Comment: Try `"[name].[hash].[ext]"` instead of `"[name].[ext]"`